# -Djava.endorsed.dirs=.... endorsed is not supported

Tags: java, eclipse, api, tomcat

Error:-Djava.endorsed.dirs=.... endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

How can I fix this error I tried many ways and nothing happens

Comment: Stick to Java 8 (if possible) or get rid of `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=...` (if possible): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/standards/

Comment: You didn't provide enough (version) information to be 100% sure, but I'm pretty sure the dup link answers it.  Either upgrade Tomcat, hack catalina.sh to remove the option, or downgrade to Java 8.  (The last is a step in the wrong direction ....)